# kurento android client library: how to get video stream from sdp offer?

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento

In kurento android, after joining the room for group video call, whenever someone connects and starts streaming, the function

`onRemoteStreamAdded(MediaStream mediaStream, NBMPeerConnection nbmPeerConnection)`

is called, and I can simply attach the mediastream with a videorenderer and it works. 
But when I join the room with existing peers publishing their videos, no media streams show up, but sdp offers are generated. How do I get video stream from all the users in the room using sdp offers?

Answer (score 0):

@aditya i have worked on M2M streaming .
I have done like this :-

```
  @Override
public void onRoomResponse(RoomResponse response) {
    int requestId = response.getId();
    boolean check = false;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : videoRequestUserMapping.entrySet()) {

        if (entry.getKey() == requestId) {
            check = true;
        }
    }
    if (check || (requestId == publishVideoRequestId)) {

        SessionDescription sd = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER,
                response.getValue("sdpAnswer").get(0));

        if (callState == CallState.PUBLISHING) {

            callState = CallState.PUBLISHED;
            nbmWebRTCPeer.processAnswer(sd, "local");
            mHandler.postDelayed(offerWhenReady, 2000);

        } else if (callState == CallState.WAITING_REMOTE_USER) {
            callState = CallState.RECEIVING_REMOTE_USER;
            String connectionId = videoRequestUserMapping.get(requestId);
            Log.e("ConnectionId", ":" + connectionId);
            nbmWebRTCPeer.processAnswer(sd, connectionId);
        } else {

            callState = CallState.RECEIVING_REMOTE_USER;
            String connectionId = videoRequestUserMapping.get(requestId);

            nbmWebRTCPeer.processAnswer(sd, connectionId);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you added the else block? I will try this, if it works I will tick that as the answer. Also, what does  this function "nbmWebRTCPeer.processAnswer(sd, connectionId);" do exactly? Thanks.

Comment: it was my logic , you can develop as you want
nbmWebRTCPeer.processAnswer(sd, connectionId); is going to generate an offer for connectionId .You have to handle the request on the basis of
requestId which you send in onIceCandidate .

Answer (score -1):

hi first you need to close the connection when someone leaves the group using

```
nbmWebRTCPeer.closeConnection("username");
```

you can manages on this method :

```
 public void onIceStatusChanged(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState     iceConnectionState, NBMPeerConnection nbmPeerConnection) {
 if (iceConnectionState.name().equalsIgnoreCase("CLOSED"))  
   {
   nbmWebRTCPeer.closeConnection(nbmPeerConnection.getConnectionId());
   }

}
```

Comment: thats not what I asked, I'm trying to use that app as a group video chat app, and I created multiple renderer views, and its working fine, as long as new people are added into the room, since i am getting meadiaStream in this function ```onRemoteStreamAdded(MediaStream mediaStream, NBMPeerConnection nbmPeerConnection)```   but when I join a room where there are existing users, I am not able to find mediaStreams of all existing users....so when I connect to the room, even if there are 5 people, I can only see 1 person.

Comment: you mean to say that , 

1) There are 5 members in room .
2)When 6th person enters into the room he/she is not able to receive mediastream of other 5 members.
3)Is 6th person was from 5 members who disconnected and then connected to room.
4)Or the 6th member is a newly joined member.

Comment: When 6th person enters into the room he/she is not able to receive mediastream of other 5 members.

Comment: its means that when 5th member enter into room he/she is not able to receive mediastream of other 4 members.
according to ur last comment .

I think ur 6th person might be one of 1 to 5 members.Your 6 person is disconnecting the call and trying to join again .

Comment: no mate, all 6 are me testing the app using 6 different computers, nobody's disconnecting anything, I'm simply asking how do you write the function to get all the mediastreams of all users from the existing room, you might understand if you go through the code in nubo-test android repository in github.

Comment: Nope. I tried your code. Didnt work. Its working for 1 on 1 video chat, not for group video call. Can you explain the workflow of this?

Comment: aditya6992@gmail.com

Comment: Please share the code to get video stream of multiple users.

Comment: @user2980181 provide your email id

Comment: sushantsingh.tanwar@gmail.com